# Applescript: iTerm to split pane from the window the script was called

Tags: bash, applescript, iterm2, iterm, osascript

I have the following script with attempts to split the window vertically, and tail a log file in the new pane.

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND="tail -f log_file"

# Do something important.
sleep 4

# Split the window, and tail logs.
osascript <<-EOF
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current session of current window
        split vertically with default profile command "$COMMAND"
    end tell
end tell
EOF
```

However, this script splits the window that is currently in focus, and not the window in which the script is running.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open an iTerm window (say W1), and run this script.
2. While the script is executing `sleep 4`, open another window (say W2) and keep W2 in focus.
3. After 4 seconds, the newer window (i.e. W2) will be split vertically.

How to open split the window from W1, the window where the script was called from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the ID of the current session at beginning of the script.

Later in the script, get the session corresponding to this identifier

```
#!/bin/bash
myID=$(osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm" to id of current session of current window')

COMMAND="tail -f log_file"

# Do something important.
sleep 4

# Split the window, and tail logs. myID2 is the id of the new session (the split pane)
myID2=$(osascript <<-EOF
tell application "iTerm"
    repeat with w in windows
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            tell (first session of t whose its id = "$myID")
                if exists then return id of (split vertically with default profile command "$COMMAND")
            end tell
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
EOF)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Is there a possibility that multiple windows with the same Id exist?